# Convert existing angular application to angular library

Tags: angular, code-reuse, angular-library

I have an existing application developed in angular 10. Now I want to convert this application as a custom library which I can import in any other projects.
I know how to created a new angular library. Thanks to [this](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/complete-beginner-guide-to-publish-an-angular-library-to-npm-d42343801660).
But my concern is :

- **Is it possible to convert an existing application to library ?**
- **If yes, How can I achive that ?**

If anyone would have any refrences or have done this before, you help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: refer here:https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/79ryxp/how_do_i_convert_my_angular_app_to_a_component/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.